# How to customize Swagger endpoint url?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have multiple web api projects (microservices), and I want to expose them using only one *swagger-ui* link.
I'll call each web api project **EndpointA** and **EndpointB** for the sake of this post.

I've created a *swagger-ui* project, and I've added each endpoint to this project.

My *swagger-ui* project `Startup.cs`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c => {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/EndpointA/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "EndpointA");
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/EndpointB/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "EndpointB");
    });
}
```

My endpoints A/B `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info
        {
            Version = "v1",
            Title = "EndpointA", // or "EndpointB",
        });
    });
}
```

---

My problem is that each of the `swagger.json` files doesn't contains the endpoint prefix. Instead of being `/EndpointA/Controller/Action`, the paths are `/Controller/Action`, which are not valid.

---

I have tried to set a custom url prefix in my swagger ui project like this `c.RoutePrefix = "EndpointA";`. It works for my *EndpointA*, but I can only set one for all endpoints so *EndpointB* won't works.

I also tried to set a prefix directly in each endpoint using `SwaggerGen`, but I don't know how / if it's possible.

Comment: If you have two web API projects, then presumably you're configuring (or could configure) two `IApplicationBuilders`.  Have you tried explicitly configuring swagger for each project?  In other words, just have a dedicated Swagger UI for each API.

Comment: @mclark1129 Of course that would work, but my question is can I have only one swagger-ui for all my projects?

Comment: Take a look here: http://swagger-net-test-multiapiversions.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index ...  On the top right, there is a dropdown to select the swagger spec, Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Yeah that's it, but with different endpoints instead of version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using the [`UsePathBaseExtensions.UsePathBase(IApplicationBuilder, PathString)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.usepathbaseextensions.usepathbase?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to register a base path to my api.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/EndpointA"));
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

---

An alternate solution would have been to use the swagger base path document filter like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
     {
         c.DocumentFilter<BasePathFilter>();
     });
 }
```

And the filter:

```
public class BasePathFilter: IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {
        swaggerDoc.BasePath = "/EndpointA";
    }
}
```